# Hiding Siblings

Tags: javascript, jquery, siblings

```
$('#navigation li.parent').mouseover(function () {
    $('#news-ticker').hide();
    $('ul.child', this).slideDown();
});
$('#navigation .child').mouseleave(function () {
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(this).hide();
        $('#news-ticker').slideDown();
    },2000);
});
```

... almost works, just one issue, how do I hide the subnav siblings? If I do `$('ul.child', this).slideDown().siblings().hide();` it hides the whole parent.

Comment: what's the HTML look like?

Comment: post your code in jsfiddle please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
$('#navigation li.parent').mouseover(function () {
  $('#news-ticker').hide();
  $(this).parent().find("ul.child").not($('ul.child', this)).hide();
  $('ul.child', this).slideDown();
});
$('#navigation .child').mouseleave(function (e) {
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(this).hide();
      $('#news-ticker').slideDown();
  },2000);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: on `mouseleave` the submenu doesn't hide but and newsticker shows on top of it

Answer (score 0):

Just hide all of your elements before you show the one you want open.

```
$('ul.child', this).hide();
$('ul.child', this).slideDown();
```

Answer (score -1):

In the slideDown method I think you can give it two parameter like so:

```
slideDown(500,function(){$(this).fadeOut(500,function(){$(this).hide();});});
```

First being interval, second being a callback function. A function called once finished.
But with your code I'd suggest using the `hover` method:

```
$('#navigation li.parent').hover(function(){
    //on mouse enter
    $('#news-ticker').hide();
    $('.child', this).slideDown(500);
},function(){
    //on mouse leave
    $('#new-ticker').slideDown(500,function(){$('.child',this).hide();});
});
```

Little hard to tell what I'm suppose to be doing without the html. Sorry.